# MySQL variable not incrementing correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Running the following query

```
SET @rownum := 0;    
SELECT customer_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, score
FROM game_table_customers gtc
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customers_id = gtc.customer_id
INNER JOIN game_table gt ON gtc.table_id = gt.table_id
WHERE c.my_team =11095
AND gt.event_id =21110
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The correct result should look like this

```
CustID  Rank    Score
2        1     130000
39       2     99426
84       3     99178
259      4     98963
339      5     97796
```

However, what I am getting is the following

```
CustID  Rank    Score
2        2      130000
39      11      99426
84      20      99178
259     54      98963
339     69  97796
```

When I exclude the event_id clause I get the correct result. However when the event_id is included it skews it. I have tried only the event_id (removing the my_team clause) and same incorrect result.

Any ideas/suggestions as to why the result may be off would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this has to do with the execution plan selected in every case and the mix with applying of row numbers - in some of those plans. The row numbers are calculated and then the `WHERE` conditions are evaluated, so you see non-consecutive row numbers.

Try this (first getting the 30 results you need, then applying row numbers):

```
SET @rownum := 0; 
SELECT customer_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, score
FROM
  ( SELECT customer_id, score
    FROM game_table_customers gtc
      INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customers_id = gtc.customer_id
      INNER JOIN game_table gt ON gtc.table_id = gt.table_id
    WHERE c.my_team =11095
      AND gt.event_id =21110
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 30
  ) tmp
ORDER BY score DESC
```

---

I can't test it now but you can also try this:

```
SELECT customer_id, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS rank, score
FROM game_table_customers gtc
  INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customers_id = gtc.customer_id
  INNER JOIN game_table gt ON gtc.table_id = gt.table_id
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0 AS rn) dummy  
WHERE c.my_team =11095
  AND gt.event_id =21110
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: hmm it indeeds works. Performance is a lot slower though due to the subquery. Are you able to explain the reasoning why this works?

Comment: Are you sure the performance is slower due to the subquery? A temp table of 30 rows should not be slowing that much.

Comment: I had to remove the limit, as there will potentially be be 1,000 rows, maybe more in time.

Comment: I suppose that `score` is in `game_table`. Do you have indexes on the columns that are used for the joins? Do you have index on `score`? I think this is valid enough for another (optimizing) question.

Comment: Doing it the wrong way was Showing rows 0 - 29 (92 total, Query took 0.0406 sec), doing it your way was Showing rows 0 - 29 (91 total, Query took 0.1078 sec). My concern is that I may need to be running this query in excess of 50 times, quite frequently to readjust the rankings based on my_team...

Comment: indexing score and table_id increases it a lot down to Showing rows 0 - 29 (91 total, Query took 0.0039 sec). Good work, thanks for ya help :)

Comment: @MattWard: You should probably [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") this answer if it helped you out.